# Leer key de diccionario con Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, selenium, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente codigo. Esta completo el programa solo que necesito un pequeño ajuste. Como podran ver, leo un diccionario y voy introduciendo las keys en distintos lugares de la web de selenium. Ahora bien, aca aparece el problema, necesito que solo me llame los keys que estan dentro del ID, no todos los del diccionario. Para ser mas claro, cuando ejecuto mi funcion, `{'829690':['testmartin','--test$2--'],` estos datos pertenecen a la primer accion del programa. el `829690` se introduce en mi URL y la llama. Luego los datos que estan dentro de `829690` los manda con `nombre.send_keys(*value)`. Ahi esta el problema, me carga tambien los de `'1016244'`.

Resultados al ejecutar el programa:

```
"https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/829690"
valores llamados: 'testmartin','--test$2--','camionetas','autos'
"https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/1016244"
valores llamados: 'testmartin','--test$2--','camionetas','autos'
```

Resultados que necesito:

```
"https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/829690"
valores llamados: 'testmartin','--test$2--'
"https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/1016244"
valores llamados: 'camionetas','autos'
```

Creo que fui claro con lo que ando buscando. Cualquier duda consultar. Dejo el codigo completo en el enlace:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlOXRzaUdRYThrQWc/view?usp=sharing

```
Lista = {'829690':['testmartin','--test$2--'], 
          '1016244':['camionetas','autos']}

for lista in Lista.itervalues():
            for value in lista:
                nombre.send_keys(*value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `dict.iteritems`, primero usa la key para crear la url, posteriormente iteras sobre las tags de esa url y así por cada clave del diccionario:

```
Lista = {'829690' :['testmartin','--test$2--'], 
         '1016244':['camionetas','autos']}

for id, tags in Lista.iteritems():
    url = driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/{}".format(id.strip()))
    # Codigo a ejecutar antes de pasar los tags

    for tag in tags:
        nombre.send_keys(tag)
```

Si te he entendido deberías hacer algo así:

```
def Target():
    for id,  tags in Lista.iteritems():
        url = driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/marketplaceconnection/{}".format(id.strip()))
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".navbar-inhiner > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.navbar-inhiner > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)').click()
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.ng-scope:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")    
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ng-scope:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)').click()
        #Cargado de tags
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ng-scope:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.ng-scope:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').click()
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s2id_autogen30"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")    
        nombre = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#s2id_autogen30')

        for tag in tags:
            nombre.send_keys(tag)
            try:
                element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select2-results-dept-0'))
                WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
            except TimeoutException:
                print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
            nombre2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.select2-results-dept-0').click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn-success:nth-child(3)').click()
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.modal-footer:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
        #Guardado de la connection

        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".bs-docs-social-buttons > li:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)"))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".bs-docs-social-buttons > li:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)").click()
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "adap-marketplace-connections-grid-filter.ng-scope > button:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Al no poder acceder a la paǵina no se si todo está identado donde debe estar, pero la idea debe ser esta.

No deberías usar clases, tu aplicación sigue un paradigma estructurado no programación orientada a objetos. No tiene sentido crear un objeto que en realidad no es tal, solo ejecuta código. Usa funciones (`def`) y las llamas en el `main` como haces con las clases.

Comment: Hice la modificacion del codigo, te dejo el link. Logre acomodar todo pero cuando la funcion tiene que ejecutar el cambio de url me salta un error. Por otro lado al usar def(target) no me ejecuta las funciones. Con class logre que las ejecute por eso uso class. Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlQ0tYSUttN1VKdVk?usp=sharing

Comment: @MartinBouhier es que no es `def (target):`, se define como `def target():` en vez de `class target()` y en el `main` se ejecuta con `target()`. Por otro lado mira el segundo código que te pongo, es `for id,  tags in Lista.iteritems():` y luego en los tags  `for tag in tags:`
        `nombre.send_keys(tag)`. Este segundo for no lo has modificado en absoluto, solo el primero. Cambia esto.

Comment: Anduvo bien, lo unico que me carga dos veces los keys. en la primer URL me carga ambos 2 veces. Sabes porque puede ser??

Comment: @MartinBouhier mirate la actualización,  he corregido el segundo código que te pongo (por si te has vasado en el ). La línea `for lista in Lista.itervalues():` sobraba, se me coló... Estoy desde el móvil y editar código es una pesadilla... :(. Creo que ya no hay ningún error excepto que exista alguno en la lógica del código (cuando se pulsa cada botón, etc) pero eso no puedo comprobarlo al no poder acceder a la url. Revisa la identación y que cada bloque se ejecute cuando toque. Ahora mismo por cada tag haces click '.select2-results-dept-0' y por cada id ejecutas la función hasta el final.

Comment: Ahi anduvo, le saque la line que modificaste y anduvo todo ok. Un detalle que no tuve en cuenta que es `"#s2id_autogen30"` el numero 30 va cambiando a medida que cambio la url. Este es el codigo: `<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen30" style="width: 10px;" placeholder="" type="text">`. Tenes alguna idea de como puedo encontrarlo para que sea automatico en cualquier url??

Comment: @MartinBouhier puedes intentar ver si puedes usar otro selector (id, class, xpath, etc) por si alguno de ellos es constante entre urls. En caso contrario sería necesario saber en base a que va cambiando y como lo hace y almacenar el selector en un diccionario por ejemplo, para que en función de la url elegir el selector adecuado (si el cambio depende de la url).

Comment: ya esta, lo que hice fue hacer un refresh en la pagina antes del cambio del url y por default me da `id="s2id_autogen30"` asique solucionado. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo el problema. Tu codigo funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, el codigo de mi dicc anda bien, tenia problemas con el armado de la funcion. Ya esta solucionado. gracias